How to give granular Access Permissions for App Registrations
Apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question.
We've had a bunch of developers ask if they can create app registrations in the Terraform environment.
Right now, it’s a no-go because the Terraform service principal doesn’t have permissions on the Entra ID. (each team has their own Terraform Service Principal).
We can’t just hand out these permissions to all Terraform principals (of each team) because of security reasons—otherwise, all DEV teams could mess around with everything in Entra ID.
Is it possible to give the developers (their terraform service principal);
Q) The permissions with more granular access on the entra ID. For example let new app registrations create but only manage the self created ones and do not have any permissions on other app registrations.
